# I am always confused with adverb placement!

Tags: adverb-placement

Which one is correct?

> 1. Overall, it can be vividly seen that the aggregated number of
>    marriages have witnessed considerable growth. Furthermore, the average
>    age of marriage **has also been increasing** throughout the mentioned
>    period of time.
> 2. Overall, it can be vividly seen that the aggregated number of
>    marriages have witnessed considerable growth. Furthermore, the average
>    age of marriage **has been also increasing** throughout the mentioned
>    period of time.

In grammar books it is often said the adverb should go after modal and before main verb. But, here, we have "has" and "been" together, so I got a little bit confused!

Comment: You probably mean: **aggregate number of marriages** and not aggregated.

Comment: [Google Ngrams](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=has+also+been%2C+has+been+also&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2Chas%20also%20been%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Chas%20been%20also%3B%2Cc0) suggests that "has been also" is quite rare.

Comment: In writing, put also here: **has also been** increasing, "was also increasing" or "did also increase", for example.  In speaking, however, you might very well actually say: has been increasing also.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> the average age of marriage ***has also been increasing*** throughout the
> mentioned period of time.

states that ***not only*** *the aggregated number of marriages* ***but also*** *the average age of marriage* have been increasing.

> the average age of marriage ***has been also increasing*** throughout the mentioned period of time.

would suggest that the average age of marriage has been ***not only increasing but also... (spreading, for example)/but even... (skyrocketing, for example)***. However, your sentence does not contain such a symmetry. That's why your first version is correct.